# SSRS parent-child list when child is sometimes empty

Tags: reporting-services, parent-child

I'm trying to build an SSRS report where the dataset is "presented" to SSRS through the application (Microsoft Dynamics NAV2009).  The concept of the report is simple - it's a list of pieces of equipment - computers, cellphones, etc.  The table has a "related to equipment" field.  So Equipment ID "CELL01" may have a "Related to equipment ID" = "Computer 123".  And Equipment ID "CAR456" may also have a "Related to equipment ID" = "Computer 123".

I want to create a report that lists each piece of equipment, and below it, any "related equipment".  Many of the pieces have no related pieces, so the listing needs to look like this:

```
COMPUTER001    Dell Latitude  4mb RAM  
COMPUTER002    Dell Latitude  16mb RAM  
COMPUTER123    Dell Latitude  8mb RAM  
    Related Equipment  
    CELL01   Nokia Cellphone  
    CAR456   2011 Ford Taurus  
COMPUTER135    Sony Laptop    12gb RAM  
CELL01         Nokia Cellphone  
CAR456         2011 Ford Taurus
```

Note that the "related items" is only unidirectional - the related items need only to be reported under the "Related to" equipment, and not vice-versa.

I have done some due diligence and investigated recursive hierarchies.  It appears that this method depends on every "child" having a "parent".  In my case, most "children" are "NULL", i.e. most equipment does not have a "related to equipment" id.  So if I try to create the list from the bottom up and use recursive hierarchies, in the example below, only the COMPUTER123 and its children would be listed.  None of the the other "Parent" records (e.g. COMPUTER001) have any children.

Has anyone done an SSRS report similar to this?  In "Pure" SQL, this would be akin to having a query using a left outer join, and listing the fields in the primary record even if the JOIN'ed results were NULL, e.g. a list of all salesmen with their orders booked for the week:

Select s.Name, i.Invoice_No, i.Invoice_Amt
from Salesperson s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice i on
s.SalespersonID = i.SalespersonID

If Salesperson "Joe" didn't make any sales this week, but Salesperson "Sam" made 3 sales  and Salesperson "Bruno" made 2 sales, You might expect a result something like this:

```
Name    Invoice_No  Invoice_Amt  
Bruno   1287        200.00  
Bruno   1289        400.00  
Joe     NULL        NULL  
Sam     1281        65.00  
Sam     1283        450.00  
Sam     1286        175.00
```

So how would you construct a Report where the output would be:

```
Bruno  
  Invoices:  
           1287    200.00  
           1289    400.00  

Joe  

Sam  
  Invoices:  
           1281     65.00  
           1283    450.00  
           1286    175.00
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Ron

Comment: After some more research, I've resolved my problem.  I needed to put the data for the parent information in a group "above" the detail lines, then the "children" records in the detail lines area.  The group lines always print, and then I put a "Visible" condition on the detail lines to only print if the values were not NULL.